# Media queries not working. Nothing is happening when I check to see if anything is working.

Tags: css, media-queries

This is my html code where I am targeting my two media queries:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="assests/css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
scale=1">
    <title>Stacy Areas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainContainer">

        <header id="navLink">
           <div class="container">
            <a href="index.html" id="logo">Stacy Areas</a>
            <nav>
              <a href="index.html">About</a>
              <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
              <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
           </nav>
          </div>
        </header>

    <div class="aboutMe">
        <div class="aboutHeader">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="aboutContent">
            <img class="aboutImage" src="assests/images/me.jpg" 
alt="stacy areas">
            <p>stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="iconLinks">
        <h3>Connect with me</h3>

        <a href="https://github.com/stacy89"><img 
src="assests/images/github.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/stacyareas/"><img 
src="assests/images/linkedin.png"></a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/7371834/stacy-areas">
<img src="assests/images/stackoverflow.png"></a>
    </div>

    <footer>copyright @ 2018 stacyareas</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css code for where I am calling my two queries. 
I feel like I have a basic understanding of how I should be using them but I'm not too experienced in using them so I could just be misunderstanding. Or maybe over looking something.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px, 768px, 640px) {
    .mainContainer {
        background-color: black;
    }       

    .iconLinks {
        width: 670px;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you have three values for max-width? There should only be one.

Comment: E.g., `max-width: 980px, 768px, 640px` isn't valid, but based on the logic implied by the three values, it should read `max-width: 980px`, since that's the maximum value and catches the other two values you're trying to target.

Comment: Ahhhh, this makes a lot of sense. I think when reading the assignment I misread. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad that was a helpful explanation.